# Does anyone know of a web based IDE?

Tags: web-ide

Does anyone know of a web based IDE (Like VS, Eclipse, IDEA)?

Besides [ECCO](http://ecco.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: No, but I'd love to hear about why anyone would need one. It's probably an obvious use-case; I've just never run across a good reason for such a thing. Do tell, please.

Answer (score 10):

[ShiftEdit Web Based IDE](http://shiftedit.net/)

Comment: I like shiftEdit, it uses Mozilla Bespin and the FTP actually works unlike a few others I've tried.

Comment: I use ShiftEdit for developing chrome extensions, it recognises all of the frameworks, has code highlighting, and source formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Bespin by Mozilla seems to be the right answer.

[link text](https://bespin.mozilla.com/)

Answer (score 1):

[Heroku](http://heroku.com/) - Ruby on Rails (RoR)

[AppJet](http://appjet.com/) - Javascript

[CodeIDE](http://www.codeide.com/) - Multi-Language

Answer (score 0):

Try [PHPAnywhere.net](http://phpanywhere.net)